# How can I identify / classify objects in a low-resolution image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning

What image recognition technology is good at identifying a low resolution object?

Specifically I want to match a low resolution object to a particular item in my database.

**Specific Example:**

Given a picture with bottles of wine, I want to identify which wines are in it. Here's an example picture:

[image]

I already have a database of high resolution labels to match to.

Given a high-res picture of an individual bottle of wine - it was very easy to match it to its label using a Vuforia (service for some image recongition).  However the service doesn't work well for lower resolution matching, like the bottles in the example image.

**Research:**

I'm new to this area of programming, so apologies for any ambiguities or obvious answers to this question.  I've been researching, but theres a huge breadth of technologies out there for image recognition.  Evaluating each one takes a significant amount of time, so I'll try to keep this question updated as I research them.

- **OpenCV**: seems to be the most popular open source computer vision library. Many modules, not sure which are applicable yet.
- **haar-cascade feature detection**: helps with pre-processing an image by orienting a component correctly (e.g. making a wine label vertical)
- **OCR**: good for reading text at decent resolutions - not good for low-resolution labels where a lot of text is not visible
- **Vuforia**: a hosted service that does some types of image recognition. Mostly meant for augmented reality developers. Doesn't offer control over algorithm. Doesn't work for this kind of resolution

Comment: That picture is bigger than FullHD, where's the low resolution? I was expecting something like 640x480 seeing that. :)

Comment: You're absolutely right.  Updating the image to one taken from my phone (which is actually what I will need to work with).

Comment: How well oriented are the bottles (i.e. is the label always centered)?  I would probably start by simplifying the problem -- you have 6 bottles in the sample image. Find the bottles and segment them. Then "flatten" each bottle to remove the distortions due to cylindrical shape. Mask out the glass. At that point you should be at a much better starting point for actual recognition. Keep reducing the size of the problem. Perhaps start with some coarse categorization based on simple features -- label shape/colour. You might need to consider that not all of the label is visible every time.

Comment: Thanks a ton Dan - let's assume good lighting, all labels centered, etc. That all sounds like great advice - do you know what I can look into for "segmenting", flattening", and "masking"?  I'm off to the google mobile and looking through openCV modules, but if you know specific things, always appreciated :)

Comment: Initially, you would probably want to look for generic bottle shapes, probably using the Haar cascade. I suppose when the labels are centered, the flattening may not be required. However, that would probably be something like the inverse of the problem of mapping a texture onto a cylinder. Mask is just a binary image, with white identifying the areas of the source image to work with. The point is to separate away anything in the background (or irrelevant to the algorithm).

Comment: First thought was neural nets - but yeah, try to isolate the objects of interest first